# Complex array sum

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I would like to add up numbers in the column based on the title of the column and the value of the column next to it. For example, I would like to add the numbers in this table:

[image: My Table]

where the column's title is `2011-2` and the column next to it (S2011-2) contains `a`. The result of this should be 3.18.

Comment: can you share the spreadsheet with us?

Answer (score 1):

That's an old one, but fairly simple to handle once you understand Database related spreadsheet functions.

In Google Spreadsheet there is `DSUM` - read through https://support.google.com/drive/answer/173497?hl=en and anlyze example spreadsheet.

In Your case do something like that:

1. Put a criteria under 'S2011-2' column, e.g. in F2 write something like `="=a"` which will resolve to `=a`
2. Use mighty DSUM: `DSUM(E1:F15;E1;F1:F2)`

Explanation:

`E1:F15` is your database, **including column names** in row 1

`E1` holds the name of column, where values are to be sum

`F1:F2` reuses column name as criteria name (F1) and applies criteria value from F2 (which is`=a` )